# Shanty_Mongo and Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, mongodb

I'm playin' around with zend framework 1.11 and mongo. I've decided to use Shanty_Mongo as a library to easy couple Zend and Mongo, but I'm stuck in this exception:

***Can not save documet. Document is not connected to a db and collection***

This is the code in the controller:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
         try {
            $guestbook = new Application_Model_Guestbook();
            $guestbook->setComment('Commento di prova')
                ->setEmail('info@example.net')
                ->save();
            $all_elements = Application_Model_Guestbook::all();
            $this->view->entries = $all_elements;
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

This is (part) of the model:

```
class Application_Model_Guestbook extends Shanty_Mongo_Document
{
      protected static $_db = 'test';
      protected static $_collection = 'user';

      protected $_comment;
         .....
```

Shanty is in my library folder, and in application.ini i've added it:

```
resources.view[] =
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Shanty"
```

On Shanty-Mongo docs, it's reported that

***"If you are connecting to localhost without any authentication then no need to worry about connections any further. Shanty Mongo will connect automatically on the first request if no connections have previously been added."***

but this does not happen.. I really can't guess why. 
Obviously, mongo is running, since if i use php Mongo() i can access it and perform insertions, etc...

I'm running the latest version of mongo, zend on php 5.3.6 on osx 10.6.8
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your model should be like this

```
 class Application_Model_Guestbook extends Shanty_Mongo_Document
 {
  protected static $_db = 'test';
  protected static $_collection = 'user';
  protected static $_requirements = array('comment'=>'Required')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to switch that autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Shanty" line to be:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = 'Shanty_Mongo'
```

Other than that it looks OK....

Comment: I've tryed it too, even if this didn't make sense to me because it actually loads shanty library.. anyway i've tryed again now and unluckily no success again.. i'm still getting the same error :(
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd error message. Notice it doesn't say "unable to connect to MongoDB" or similar. It says that this document isn't connected to a collection. It sounds like a configuration issue to me.

In other areas of your code are you able to connect to the database?

Read from the database?

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer. I wrote this as a test, so I've no other access to db from other points in my code. If you meant "can yo successfulluy connect to mongo in some other ways", actually I can write / read to Mongo using php driver.. as a test, i've cut and pasted the code on http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php and it successfully worked.

Answer (score 0):

Allesio,

the element that both you and Adam C have put on the autoloaderNamespaces array are not quite correct. Try the following:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Shanty_"
```

You only need to put the top-level prefix followed by an underscore. Please let me know if this doesn't resolve the situation. Also, I've not seen that error message before. For sure, if you have a local install of mongoDB running, you won't need to specify any authentication parameters.

If the collection doesn't exist, Shanty will create it and if the document doesn't exist, Shanty will create that as well.

What operating system are you using?

I had a number of troubles with the package in the Ubuntu repositories. However, adding the 10gen repository in to apt and installing the latest stable version helped me out. Though even that seems to crash periodically.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your assistance!!! I've tried as you suggested, but it didn't worked. 
I'm sure Shanty is loaded correctly, because the exception message is in Shanty code, specifically in Document, at row 907. 
Here's my configuration in detail:

I'm running php 5.3.6 on OSX 10.6.8 
Mongo is up and running, 
Db files are on my hd root(/data/db) 
Project files are on /Volumes/Data/Sites/test/, 
Project url is test.local

I can't really understand why Shanty cannot connect to it..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to Bootstrap.php:

```
  protected function _initMongoDB() {
    $connection = new Shanty_Mongo_Connection('mongodb://localhost:27017'); 
    Shanty_Mongo::addMaster($connection);
  }
```